# BigQuery: Convert record of repeated in repeated record

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table represented by this JSON (**Record of Repeated**)

```
{
  "createdBy": [
    "foo",
    "foo"
  ],
  "fileName": [
    "bar1",
    "bar2"
  ]
}
```

that I need to convert to **Repeated Record**

```
[
      {
        "createdBy": "foo",
        "fileName": "bar1"
      },
      {
        "createdBy": "foo",
        "fileName": "bar2"
      }
]
```

To make this conversion you use the index 0 for every array and you created the first object, use the 1 index for the second object, ...

I performed this kind of transformation using a UDF, but the problem is due to BigQuery limits I'm unable to save a VIEW that performs this transformation:

```
No support for CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION statements inside views
```

Following the full statement to generate a sample table and the function

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION filesObjectArrayToArrayObject(filesJson STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<createdBy STRING, fileName STRING>>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
    function filesObjectArrayToArrayObject_execute(files) {   
      var createdBy = files["createdBy"];
      var fileName = files["fileName"];
      var output = [];
      for(var i=0 ; i<createdBy.length ; i++) {
        output.push({ "createdBy" : createdBy[i], "fileName" : fileName[i] });
      }
      return output;
    }
    return filesObjectArrayToArrayObject_execute(JSON.parse(filesJson));
  """;

WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT STRUCT<createdBy ARRAY<STRING>, fileName ARRAY<STRING>>(
    ["foo", "foo"],
    ["bar1", "bar2"]
  ) AS files
)

SELECT
  files AS filesOriginal,
  filesObjectArrayToArrayObject(TO_JSON_STRING(files)) AS filesConverted

FROM sample_table
```

Is there a way to perform the same kind of task using native BigQuery statements?

Please note that:

- The real data has more than 2 keys, but those are fixed in names
- The length of the array is not fixed, can be 0, 1, 10, 20, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT STRUCT<createdBy ARRAY<STRING>, fileName ARRAY<STRING>>(
    ["foo", "foo"],
    ["bar1", "bar2"]
  ) AS files
)
SELECT 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT STRUCT(createdBy, fileName) 
    FROM t.files.createdBy AS createdBy WITH OFFSET
    JOIN t.files.fileName AS fileName WITH OFFSET
    USING(OFFSET)
  ) files
FROM `sample_table` t
```

with output

```
Row files.createdBy files.fileName   
1   foo             bar1     
    foo             bar2
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to use `LEFT JOIN` as some fields in array are null, but I created the query with the actual data and it is working fine